# How does choosing between pre and post zero padding of sequences impact results

Tags: machine-learning, recurrent-neural-network, model-evaluation

I'm working on an NLP sequence labelling problem. My data consists of variable length sequences `(w_1, w_2, ..., w_k)` with corresponding labels `(l_1, l_2, ..., l_k)` (in this case, named entity extraction).

I intend to solve the problem using Recurrent Neural Networks. As the sequences are of variable length I need to pad them (I want batch size >1). I have the option of either pre zero padding them, or post zero padding them. I.e. either I make every sequence `(0, 0, ..., w_1, w_2, ..., w_k)` or `(w_1, w_2, ..., w_k, 0, 0, ..., 0)` such that the lenght of each sequence is the same. How does the choice between pre- and post padding impact results?